# Android charts: achartengine or AndroidPlot?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine, androidplot

I want to develop an activity to display sensor data in a plot. I've been looking around and I have found that the more interesting options for me are **achartengine** and **AndroidPlot**.

I need the following requirements:

1. Line plot with 3 or more series
2. Dynamic plots
3. Integration with a layout with other GUI
4. Integration with database

I think that both libraries are ok with my requirements, but could someone tell me from his experience which one is better? Which one is easier to integrate with an app?

Comment: For the moment I will do the dev using AndroidPlot, because it's the one with more info in the web.

Comment: How was your development experience?  Did you have any setbacks using AndroidPlot?  Did you try AChartEngine for a comparison by chance?

Comment: Android plot was useful and easy to integrate, so for the moment I have only worked with it (I have not tried AChartEngine yet). You can easily set up basic graphs and has enough capabilities to personalize it for your apps

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't look at AChartEngine but have used AndroidPlot and can relay my experience here.

I've successfully had multiple lines on my chart being updated in realtime (Req 1&2) and this chart has been embedded inside of another control (Req 3).

For Req 4, I haven't worked with a db but my guess is that you would have to write the code to do the query and update the chart yourself.

Answer (score 6):

I think AchartEngine is better because you have lots of flexibility. and it is a open source library.there is a good number  community to help you out. It's a better library if you want different kind of bars in your application.

Comment: They are both open source actually.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use AChartEngine, you can get a complete example from [here.](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/)

Comment: The images shown are a little disconcerting...I would think AChartEngine supports label/axis padding?  Is there something AChartEngine does that AndroidPlot doesn't?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the usage metrics on http://appbrain.com, currently AChartEngine is used by 0.61% of the 700K applications while AndroidPlot is used by 0.17%. All the other metrics show an even higher difference in usage. Hmmmm....

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/details/achartengine

http://www.appbrain.com/stats/libraries/details/androidplot