# Android charting libraries

Tags: android, charts, achartengine, androidplot, mpandroidchart

I am trying to find a fast and reliable charting library. After some searching, I found 4 libraries: [AChartEngine](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine) [warning! official website is down and redirects to virus filled website!], [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart), [HelloCharts](https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android) and [AndroidPlot](http://androidplot.com/). I need some up to date feedback about the performance and the stability of these libraries because all the information I could find was outdated.

Comment: `AChartEngine` is the best choice at the moment (among the open source libraries)

Comment: Would be interesting why you think so? ;)

Comment: Currently I'm working on forex mobile client app. Candlestick chart is required. We spent lot of time, and `AChartEngine` looks much better then others. I optimized it's rendering time from `270ms` per frame to `80ms` in a few hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android charts: achartengine or AndroidPlot?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730827/android-charts-achartengine-or-androidplot)

Comment: There's some very up to date info comparing Android Chart Performance of 5x libraries plus a newcomer SciChart here: http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-performance-comparison/

Comment: that comparison is pretty sketchy.  at the very least they could publish the code they are using to benchmark their competitor's apps. would be very surprised if the benchmark differences arent caused by preferential usage of a downsampling technique like LTTB, which could also have been used any other lib for probably an equal or greater benchmark result on large datasets.

Comment: Also: [Android Chart Lib Comparison](http://codix.io/cmp/Android%20Charting%20Libraries)

Comment: **AChartEngine** looks abandoned. **AndroidPlot** and **MPAndroidChart** look good - I especially like the demo source code for MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can use [**MPAndroidChart**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

It's native, free, easy to use, fast and reliable.

**[Core features](https://weeklycoding.com/mpandroidchart/core-features/), benefits:**

- LineChart, BarChart (vertical, horizontal, stacked, grouped), PieChart, ScatterChart, CandleStickChart (for financial data), RadarChart (spider web chart), BubbleChart
- Combined Charts (e.g. lines and bars in one)
- Scaling on both axes (with touch-gesture, axes separately or pinch-zoom)
- Dragging / Panning (with touch-gesture)
- Separate (dual) y-axes
- Highlighting values (with customizeable **popup-views**)
- Save chart to SD-Card (as image)
- Predefined color templates
- Legends (generated automatically, customizeable)
- Customizeable Axes (both x- and y-axis)
- Animations (build up animations, on both x- and y-axis)
- Limit lines (providing additional information, maximums, ...)
- Listeners for touch, gesture & selection callbacks
- Fully customizeable (paints, typefaces, legends, colors, background, dashed lines, ...)
- [Realm.io](https://realm.io) mobile database support via [MPAndroidChart-Realm](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart-Realm) library
- Smooth rendering for up to **10.000** data points in Line- and BarChart
- Lightweight (method count ~1.4K)
- Available as **.jar file** (only 500kb in size)
- Available as **gradle dependency** and via **maven**
- Good [documentation](https://weeklycoding.com)
- [Example Project](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample) (code for demo-application)
- [Google-PlayStore Demo Application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxmassdeveloper.mpchartexample)
- Widely used, great support on both [GitHub](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues) and stackoverflow - [mpandroidchart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mpandroidchart)
- Also available for **iOS**: [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) (API works the same way)
- Also available for **Xamarin**: [MPAndroidChart.Xamarin](https://github.com/Flash3001/MPAndroidChart.Xamarin)

**Drawbacks:**

- No official support for **[dynamic & realtime](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Dynamic-&-Realtime-Data)** data, limited performance in that area

*Disclaimer: I am the developer of this library.*

Comment: I particulary like this library. clean and beautiful.nicely done thanks. I think I am going with this Charting Lib.

Comment: Any concerns about performance that we should pay attention to ?

Comment: It varies but it's usually 10 to 20 objects.

Comment: I would not worry for up to 1000 objects - if you are using line or barchart, 10.000 - 20.000 objects should be possible

Comment: I'm currently using MpChart and on three years old tablets I can easily plot up to 15000 points ;)

Comment: If I wanted to just pull the "Bar" from the bar chart, would it be possible? Please see post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35346511/how-to-programatically-create-a-bar-displaying-poll-results-under-answer-option

Comment: @PhilippJahoda The library is good, but this leads to the "unable to execute dex" issue as i need other libraries as well. I only want to use the bar chart function. I trimmed the library but it is still having the same issue. Is there any other ways to reduce the methods so that i would use it in my project?

Comment: The library has approximately 1.400 methods. That is not a very big number  (compared to others) and should not really affect the 65K limit unless you have either a huge number of other libraries or libraries that have a significantly higher method count (e.g. Play Services 30K, AppCompat 12K, ... ). This means that optimization is probably more suitable elsewhere. Also it is possible to [build apps with more than 65K methods](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html).

Comment: I have to say that the lack of Time Series is a huge turn down. I spent some time to integrate this awesome lib until I found there is no way I can scale the x axis properly with date/time.

Comment: but can't use strings in y axis right?

Comment: does it supported following feature, multiple values of y-axis for single x-axis point? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656960/duplicate-x-axis-value-in-mpandroidchart-library

Comment: It seems MPAndroidChart support only equidistant values for X-axis. It's a disadvantage.

Comment: SciChart supports time-series as well as Date-series and non-equidistant values for X-Axis. It also outperforms MPAndroidCharts for streaming / realtime applications https://www.scichart.com/android-charts

Comment: is it possible to draw multiple line chart with different gradient (Ex: line1(red, green), line 2 (blue, yellow) in a single chart.) because as i know gradient we can apply on Chart not in Line. Please suggest if possible

Comment: Hi Philipp, This library now free or not? I need to render dynamic data's. Totally confused :(

Comment: Does  it have gauge chart ?

Comment: is there any way to update an entry at a specific index in the pie chart?

Comment: This open source project has not been updated for a long time...

Answer (score 87):

See [Android arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/) (category Graphics) for more libraries.

- [AChartEngine](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine)
- [AFreeChart](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/AFreeChart)
- [AndroidCharts](https://github.com/HackPlan/AndroidCharts)
- [Androidplot](http://androidplot.com/)
- [DroidDiagram](http://www.mindfusion.eu/droid-diagram.html)
- [EazeGraph GraphView](https://github.com/blackfizz/EazeGraph)
- [HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary)
- [HzGrapher](https://github.com/handstudio/HzGrapher)
- [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)
- [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com/android-chart-features)
- [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart)
- [ChartProgressBar](https://github.com/hadiidbouk/ChartProgressBar-Android)

Comment: This is the best answer simply because it provides a comprehensive list of possible libraries.

Comment: Based on Android Arsenal the best chart library are MPAndroidChart

Comment: @chenshuiluke unfortunatelly all but one lib are dead :-\

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking for something more straight forward to implement (and it doesn't include pie/donut charts) then I recommend [WilliamChart](https://github.com/diogobernardino/WilliamChart). Specially if motion takes an important role in your app design. In other hand if you want featured charts, then go for [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).

Comment: I need the pie chart type in my app, this is why I choosed MPAndroidChart, plus it has some nice rendered charts

Answer (score 6):

[AchartEngine](https://github.com/ddanny/achartengine)

You can create a plethora of different chart types relatively quickly with loads of customizable options.

Answer (score 5):

- Achartengine: I have used this. Although for real time graph this might not give good performance if you do not tweak properly.