# How to Programatically Create A Bar Displaying Poll Results Under Answer Option

Tags: java, android, view

I am creating a polling application and would like to generate a bar that displays the poll results in real-time. In other words, the bar will update as users answer poll questions.

This UI has to be done programmatically, as I am going to be pulling poll results from Firebase. I have explored the idea of creating a basic View underneath my TextView, as shown below. However, I am interested to hear if there are any known libraries or other methods of displaying the results:

[image]

And my code so far:

```
public void addRadioButtonsWithFirebaseAnswers(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, int numberOfAnswers) {
    mPollAnswerArrayList = new ArrayList<RadioButton>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfAnswers; i++) {
        mPollAnswerArrayList.add(i, new RadioButton(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        String firebaseChild = String.valueOf(i + 1);
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setText(dataSnapshot.child("Poll_Answers").child(firebaseChild).getValue().toString());
        mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        mParams.setMarginStart(120);
        mPollQuestionRadioGroup.addView(mPollAnswerArrayList.get(i), mParams);
        View barResult = new View(getContext());
        barResult.setBackgroundColor(R.color.actionRed);
        barResult.setMinimumHeight(1);
        barResult.setMinimumWidth(1);
        mPollQuestionRadioGroup.addView(barResult, mParams);

    }
```

Comment: I have found this library, but it seems to no longer be maintained: https://github.com/PhilJay/ValueBar