# Duplicate x-axis value in MPAndroidchart library

Tags: duplicates, label, mpandroidchart

```
//map: {2-6-2016=[120.0], 27-5-2016=[100.0], 1-6-2016=[78.0, 59.0]}

LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);
 ArrayList<Entry> graphYValues = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> xLabels = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Map.Entry<String, List<Float>> mapKeySet : map.entrySet()) {
                List<Float> lsValue = mapKeySet.getValue();

                for (float v : lsValue) {
                    graphYValues.add(new Entry(v, i));//value ,index
                   xLabels.add(mapKeySet.getKey());//if same label -x-axis have multiple y-axis value on same x-label axis
               }

                i++;
            }
   LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(graphYValues,"Graph for "+spTestSubElement.getSelectedItem().toString());
 LineData data = new LineData(xLabels,dataset);
   lineChart.setData(data);
```

[image]

It created duplicate entry for x-axis label.How can plot graph for multiple y values on same x-axis point ?How to solve this issue.

Comment: You are adding multiple time xLabels.

Comment: How to get Multiple Y values for “single Date” value(as X axis) in single series ?map: {2-6-2016=[120.0], 27-5-2016=[100.0], 1-6-2016=[78.0, 59.0]},date is x-axis label ,float value-y axis

Comment: How you have displayed `1-6-2016=[78.0, 59.0]` in same X-axis? As of now, forget about multiple X-axis. Same way you need to do for X-axis.

Comment: My graph is plotted properly ,But it just created duplicate labels

Comment: if i am not added x-axis value twice ,it throw exception [ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: One or more of the DataSet Entry arrays are longer than the x-values array of this ChartData object ]

Comment: @PranitaPatil were you able to get any resolution for this.