# Android customised box plot chart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

How do I implement a box plot graph on Android like this? It seems to be similar to CandleStick Chart of MPAndroidChart. Is there any other good way?

[image: a box and whiskers chart]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CandleStickChart is the closest match to your requirement for that library in MPAndroidChart although you could have a look at the other chart libraries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26467376/android-charting-libraries) 
to see if there is anything closer.

The CandleStickChart from MPAndroidChart looks like this:[image: a CandleStickChart]

[CandleStickChartActivity](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CandleStickChartActivity.java) in the example GitHub project is a good start for you to base your implementation.

If you need to customise the appearance of the chart further (e.g., to use circles instead of boxes) you will need to write a custom renderer. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer) for how to do that.